# asp.net MVC, how to work with HTTPApplication class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpapplication

How do I go about gathering site statistics in MVC?  (users online.. etc?)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you can use the same techniques as for normal ASP.NET web apps: user's counter increment at OnSessionStart in global.asax or similar or you can write your own event handler to be put the request processing queque.

For offline statistics can use google analytics with their "sonda code" put into master page.

twk